# Which is the proper way to read data from advertiser in BLE in Xamarin forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm trying to **read large amount of data in BLE**. I'm getting **data in chunks from advertiser**. So I'm getting the data through **notification**. But the data I'm receiving is not proper sometimes it's **repeated or it's incomplete**. This is my code where I'm getting data in **notification**.

```
characteristicRead.ValueUpdated += (o, e) =>
            {
                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                {
                    //var readvalue2 = characteristics.Value;
                    var bytes = e.Characteristic.Value;
                    //var readvalue = await characteristics.ReadAsync();
                    BLEresultnew = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
                    
                    Console.WriteLine(BLEresultnew);
                    concat += BLEresultnew;
                    
                    
                });
            };
```

**This how the data should be coming from the advertiser**

> start{"command":"UnitConfig","enhancements":[{"name":"fruit","status":"Available"}],"flavors":[{"name":"Black
> Cherry","status":"Available"}],"vegetable":[],"water":[{"name":"Still","status":"Available"}]}end

**But sometimes the data is repeated like**

> start{"command":"UnitConfig" "UnitConfig","enhancements":[{"name":"fruit\ "fruit","status":"Available""Available"}],"flavors":[{"name":"Black
> Cherry","status":"Available"}],"vegetable":[],"water":[{"name":"Still","status":"Available"}]}end

**And sometimes even the data at the starting is missing like**

> Config","enhancements":[{"name":"fruit\ "fruit","status":"Available""Available"}],"flavors":[{"name":"Black
> Cherry","status":"Available"}],"vegetable":[],"water":[{"name":"Still","status":"Available"}]}end

is it the way I'm **reading the data in BLE**  wrong? How to solve these types of read issue in BLE? Any suggestion?

Comment: If you piece together the incomplete chunks, do they for a valid chunk?  I.e. is the data just chunked in an unfortunate manner, are the chunks out of sequence, or are some chunks missing?

Comment: @dbc from the advertiser they are send it in order in chunks. But while receiving it it's either incomplete or not proper.

Comment: @JudsonAbraham If you can add `start` flag and `end` flag for data, then you could receive the data according to two flags to better know which time the data be receiced and which time be finished.

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT yes for that I'm putting condition  if (BLEobj.Contains("start")). But what should I do for the data that is reapeated?

Comment: @JudsonAbraham The `start` and `end` flag is abstract define, you could only add `\n` char in the end of data. If detect this char, that means the data has been received completely.

Answer (score 1):

The underlying issue is that the BLE library which it looks like you are using (dotnet-bluetooth-le) uses a common buffer for each notification chunk. So if don't process the buffer fast enough then it will get overwritten before you read it.

The simple hacky fix is to accumulate the buffer outside of the Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread (which is what's causing the delay - waiting for the main thread to become available).

The better fix would be for the library to be fixed to return the byte array properly, rather than a reference to the common buffer.